# replacing a founded value in a function

Tags: functions, replacement

Here is the sample

```
F[r_] := r^2 + r^3
DerivI[r_] := D[F[r], r]
A = FindRoot[DerivI[r], {r, 9}]
B = F[r] /. r -> A
```

I want to replace `A` in `B`; it finds `A` perfectly, but when try to substitute `A` in `B` it does not give a numeric value, it writes `r -> 8.59768*10^-17` in `B`. How can I get a numeric value for `B`?

Comment: As you see `A` is replacement rule, so you don't need `r -> A`, just use `A` like: `B = F[r] /. A`.

Comment: `Solve[F'[r] == 0, r]`

Comment: It worked Alx. I thought I should replace r with RB first, my bad.